# Find if a Map contains a value from a Set

Tags: java, java-8

I want to see if any value in my Set is used in as a key in a Map.

I could do:

```
Set<String> foo;
for (String val: foo) {
    if (map.containsKey(val)) {
        contains = true;
        break
    }
}
```

Is there anything cooler?

Comment: What version of Java?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Look at tags

Comment: `boolean contains = !Collections.disjoint(foo, map.keySet())`

Answer (score 8):

```
boolean contains = foo.stream()
                      .anyMatch(map::containsKey);
```

Not sure if that is *cooler*.

Comment: totally radical

Comment: @Michael as radical as it gets! yeah, feel weird now after your comment

Comment: lots of people feel this way after my comments

Comment: Sure it is. The only thing that would be even cooler, would be a `containsAny` method in the `Collection` interface in addition to `containsAll`. Don’t know why it doesn’t exist…